# Proof of following statement.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How will you prove :

> For a diagonal matrix, the algebraic and geometric multiplicities of eigenvalues coincide, and therefore the same holds for the diagonalizable operators.

If $A$ is a diagonalizable operator then $A = SDS^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. Say for a eigenvalue $\lambda$, the algebraic multiplicity is $p$, then I need to prove that $\dim \operatorname{Ker}(A - \lambda I) = p$. I know  $\dim \operatorname{Ker}(D - \lambda I) = p$.

Since $\det (D - r I) =\det (A - r I) = (r - \lambda)^p q(r)$ where $q$ is polynomial and $q(\lambda) \ne 0$.

How do I proceed from here ? Any hints.

Comment: are you familiar with the Jordan canonical form?

Comment: @user3002473 No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is diagonalizable as $A = S^{-1}DS$. Then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is equal to the characteristic polynomial of $D$, which is
$$
\chi_D(t) = \prod_{\lambda\in\sigma(A)}(t-\lambda)^{a(\lambda)}
$$
where $\sigma(A)$ is the **spectrum** of $A$ (the set of unique eigenvalues of $A$), and $a(\lambda)$ is the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ (which, due to the diagonal form of $D$, is equal to the number of times $\lambda$ occurs in $D$).

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A$ permits an **eigenbasis**. In more detail, if $A:X\to X$, then there is a basis $B$ for $X$ consisting entirely of eigenvectors of $A$). Suppose
$$
[A]_B = D = \text{diag}(\underbrace{\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_1}_{a(\lambda_1)},\underbrace{\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_2}_{a(\lambda_2)},\cdots,\lambda_k)
$$
(again, we know there are $a(\lambda_1)$ occurrences of $\lambda_1$ along the diagonal because of the characteristic polynomial for $D$. Also, I use $[A]_B$ to denote "$A$ w.r.t. basis $B$").

Lets suppose our basis is $B = \{x_1,\cdots, x_n\}$. If $A$ written with respect to $B$ takes the form $D$ above, then
$$
[A]_Bx_1 = \lambda_1x_1 \\
[A]_Bx_2 = \lambda_1x_2 \\
\vdots \\
[A]_Bx_{a(\lambda_1)} = \lambda_1x_{a(\lambda_1)} \\
[A]_Bx_{a(\lambda_1)+1} = \lambda_2x_{a(\lambda_1)+1} \\
\vdots \\
[A]_Bx_{a(\lambda_1)+a(\lambda_2)} = \lambda_2x_{a(\lambda_1)+a(\lambda_2)} \\
[A]_Bx_{a(\lambda_1)+a(\lambda_2)+1} = \lambda_3 x_{a(\lambda_1) + a(\lambda_2) + 1} \\
\vdots
$$
and so on in that fashion. This means, there are $a(\lambda_1)$ eigenvectors in our eigenbasis corresponding to $\lambda_1$, $a(\lambda_2)$ eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_2$, and so on.

From here we can start to see how it would make sense that $a(\lambda) = g(\lambda)$ (where $g(\lambda)$ is the geometric multiplicity, equal to $\dim\ker(A - \lambda I)$), the intuition being that if the eigenbasis spans the entire space $X$, then we should expect that the eigenvectors in the basis corresponding to a given $\lambda$ also span that $\lambda$-eigenspace, since otherwise there would be an eigenvector of $A$ that isn't obtainable by the basis $B$ (since bases of different eigenspaces are linearly independent). Let's prove this rigorously.

First, we prove that the union bases of different eigenspaces is linearly independent. To do this, simply note that eigenspaces for different eigenvalues are disjoint (except for $0$), since if $Tx = \lambda_1 x = \lambda_2 x$ (for $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$), then $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2)x = 0$, implying $x=0$, so the only vector in both the $\lambda_1$-eigenspace and the $\lambda_2$-eigenspace is the zero vector. So suppose $\{x_1,\cdots, x_m\}$ spans the first eigenspace, and $\{y_1,\cdots, y_n\}$ the second, and suppose $a_1x_1+\cdots + a_mx_m = b_1y_1+\cdots + b_ny_n$. Then since the sum of eigenvectors is an eigenvector, by the above argument both sides must be identically zero, and so all the coefficients must be zero.

Now, assume in our basis $B$, the $\lambda$-eigenvectors (for a given $\lambda$) *don't* span the $\lambda$-eigenspace. Then there is a $\lambda$-eigenvector $v$ that is unreachable by our basis $B$ (since the only vectors whose linear combination could ever possibly equal a $\lambda$-eigenvector *are* the $\lambda$-eigenvectors in $B$), meaning $B$ isn't a basis for $X$, which is a contradiction. Hence, the $\lambda$-eigenvectors in $B$ must span the $\lambda$-eigenspace.

This, in conclusion, tells us that there are $g(\lambda)=\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)$ eigenvectors in our eigenbasis $B$, and so $g(\lambda)$ occurrences of $\lambda$ along the diagonal. So $g(\lambda) = a(\lambda)$.

Comment: the "this" in "But this is equal to the number of occurrences..." is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ right ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @123 is there anything else you're having trouble with, or you feel is unresolved in the three answers? If not, please select what you feel is the best answer.

Comment: Where did you use "The number of vectors in the basis corresponding to eigenvector $λ$ is equal to the number of vectors required to span the $λ$-eigenspace" ? You only used the fact that $\dim \ker(A - \lambda I)$ equals number of $\lambda$s in the diagonal of $D$, no ?

Comment: @123 I admit my previous proof was a little "hand-wavey" because I didn't have much time. I put in more rigor, hopefully that clears up the confusion.

Comment: @user3002473 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If the matrix is diagonalizable then clearly each of the Jordan blocks will be of size $1$. Which means along the diagonal of the matrix we will have just the eigenvalues of $A$.

Consider the minimal polynomial of $A$, $m(t)=(t-\lambda_1)\cdots(t-\lambda_n)$. Notice that the algebraic multiplicities of the roots of $m(t)$ are all $1$, but these exponents represent $\dim K_{\lambda_i}$ where $K_{\lambda_i}$ is the generalized $\lambda_i$-eigenspace.

Clearly though if $\dim K_{\lambda_i}=1$ we would require that $K_{\lambda_i} = E_{\lambda_i}$ where $E_{\lambda_i}$ is the $\lambda_i$-eigenspace of $A$, but this is equal to the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about Jordan blocks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you have eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_s$, repeated $k_1,\dots, k_s$ times, the characteristic polynomial of a diagonal matrix $D$ is
$$\chi_D(x)=\prod_{i=1}^s(x-\lambda_i)^{k_1}.$$

If the diagonal matrix is $\lambda I_n$, it amounts to checking  that $\dim\ker(0)=n =\deg(x-\lambda)^n$.

For a general diagonal matrix, it is obvious from block multiplication  that $\ker(D-\lambda_iI)$ is generated by the $k_i$ vectors of the canonical basis:
$$e_{k_1+\dots+k_{i-1}+1}, \dots,e_{k_1+\dots+k_{i-1}+k_i}. $$
whence geometric and algebraic mutiplicities are again equal.

Comment: Can you expand on what are "vectors of canonical basis" ?

Comment: Well, as usual, $e_1=(1,0,0,\dots)$, $e_2=(0,1,0,\dots)$ and so on.